# How to pass value to onclick callback using this.props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created array of buttons as shown below in the code section. I am using sandbox. what i want to do is, when i click button 3 i should receive in the console

```
button 3
```

and so on.

please let me know how should i pass value to onClick callback

**code**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";

var arrButtons = [];
var buttonStyle = {
  margin: "10px 10px 10px 0"
};

class ButtonClicks extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickFunction = this.onClickFunction.bind(this);
  }
  onClickFunction() {
    console.log("button ");
    console.log(this.props.log);
  }
  render() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      //Moved your loop outside render()'s return
      arrButtons.push(
        <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.onClickFunction}>
          {i}
          {this.props.i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {arrButtons} {/*Very important to wrap the buttons inside a div*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ButtonClicks />, rootElement);

export default ButtonClicks;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new inline function that passes the index to your `onClickFunction`.

**Example**

```js
const buttonStyle = {
  margin: "10px 10px 10px 0"
};

class ButtonClicks extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickFunction = this.onClickFunction.bind(this);
  }
  onClickFunction(index) {
    console.log(`button ${index}`);
  }
  render() {
    const arrButtons = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      arrButtons.push(
        <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={() => this.onClickFunction(i)}>
          {i}
          {this.props.i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        {arrButtons}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ButtonClicks />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @LetsamrIt Sadly not. `this.props` are the props that are passed in to the `ButtonClicks` component, not what is passed into the `onClickFunction` function.

Comment: @LetsamrIt Consider accepting one of the answers if you feel any of them answered your question.

Comment: @LetsamrIt That's frustrating. [It works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/mjrlqvk158).

Comment: hi.maybe you can answer this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637575/how-to-link-onclick-callback-to-call-external-file

Answer (score 0):

Just try with creating dynamically an anonymous function that invokes your `onClickFunction`:

```
<button style={buttonStyle} onClick={() => this.onClickFunction(i)}>
```

Now your `onClickFunction` can take an argument:

```
onClickFunction(i) {
  console.log(`button ${i}`);
}
```

Comment: sadly, the log inside onClickfunction does not work in sandbab??

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value as params to the callback function, not as a props.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arrButtons.push(
    <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={()=>this.onClickFunction(i)}>
      {i}
    </button>
  );
}
```

pass the value `onClick` button. and receive in function as below.

```
onClickFunction(i) {
  console.log("button ",i);
  console.log('value received as params not as props like this.props.log');
}
```