# How to link onclick callback to call external file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created array of buttons, let say I have 20 buttons. I have 20 mp3 files as well. Now what i want to do is to link the button callback "onclick" with a 
specific .mp3 file. So that, when the button number 5 is clicked, the 5th mp3 will be executed. how can I achieve this task by modifying the below
posted code? please provide an example.

**note**: the mp3 files are save locally on the hard drive.

please let me know how should i pass value to onClick callback

**code**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";

var arrButtons = [];
var buttonStyle = {
  margin: "10px 10px 10px 0"
};

class ButtonClicks extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickFunction = this.onClickFunction.bind(this);
  }
  onClickFunction() {
    console.log("button ");
    console.log(this.props.log);
  }
  render() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      //Moved your loop outside render()'s return
      arrButtons.push(
        <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.onClickFunction}>
          {i}
          {this.props.i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {arrButtons} {/*Very important to wrap the buttons inside a div*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ButtonClicks />, rootElement);

export default ButtonClicks;
```

Comment: Do you need Button you can directly give URL or path of mp3 in `<a>` tag it will start downloading

Answer (score 0):

You would benefit from using JS's .map and creating a button that has a unique onClick passing that specific mp3's id back into your onClick function. From there you can lookup by id, then play only that specific file.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";


class ButtonClicks extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {mp3Files}
    this.onClickFunction = this.onClickFunction.bind(this);
  }
  onClickFunction(mp3UniqueIdToLookup) {
    console.log("button ");
    console.log(this.props.log);
    //Here you would search your files for the mp3 with the corresponding id and then play that one only.
  }
  render() {
    const buttonStyle = {
      margin: "10px 10px 10px 0"
    };

    return (
      <div>
       {this.state.mp3Files.map((index, ele) => {
         return <button style={buttonStyle} key={index} onClick={() => this.onClickFunction(ele.id)}/>
       })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ButtonClicks />, rootElement);

export default ButtonClicks;
```

Comment: would you please explain, why did you used this.state.mp3Files instead of this.props.mp3Files? (2)what and why ele.id (3) what is this.props.log

Comment: @LetsamrIt I think Gavin use state instead of props because using local state makes the example snippet to appear more complete without lift the state and add to example out-of-topic code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. While doing loop you can pass the no to event handler function and access the no. This is how it works when you do looping

**ES5 way**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";

var arrButtons = [];
var buttonStyle = {
  margin: "10px 10px 10px 0"
};

class ButtonClicks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickFunction = this.onClickFunction.bind(this);
  }
  onClickFunction(no) {
    console.log("Here you will get button no. if you click button 5 you will get button no 5 and you can pass the same to log");
    console.log(this.props.log(no));
  }
  render() {
    for (let i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
      arrButtons.push(
        <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.onClickFunction(i)}>
          {i}
          {this.props.i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {arrButtons} {/*Very important to wrap the buttons inside a div*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ButtonClicks />, rootElement);

export default ButtonClicks;
```

**ES6 way**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";

var arrButtons = [];
var buttonStyle = {
  margin: "10px 10px 10px 0"
};

class ButtonClicks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  onClickFunction = (no) => {
    console.log("Here you will get button no. if you click button 5 you will get button no 5 and you can pass the same to log");
    console.log(this.props.log(no));
  }
  render() {
    for (let i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
      arrButtons.push(
        <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.onClickFunction(i)}>
          {i}
          {this.props.i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {arrButtons} {/*Very important to wrap the buttons inside a div*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ButtonClicks />, rootElement);

export default ButtonClicks;
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that you give your buttons the IDs of their index and receiving them in the `onClickFunction` like this

```
onClickFunction(e) {
    var mp3Index = parseInt(e.target.id);
    console.log("button ");
    console.log(this.props.log);
  }
  render() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      //Moved your loop outside render()'s return
      arrButtons.push(
        <button id={i} style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.onClickFunction}>
          {i}
          {this.props.i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {arrButtons} {/*Very important to wrap the buttons inside a div*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

from there you may proceed on how to use their index.